# In OpenERP, Import and Export menu not shown

Tags: openerp-7

I'm learning **OpenERP**. I created a new **Database** but I want to **import csv file** but not seeing it's menu. Can Any one help me where from I get?

Thanks in Advance,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following step try it.

- **Setting Menu => Configuration => General Settings**
- You See the **Import / Export menu**. Now mark it **True** and than go your place where you want to import or Export file.

Hope you will see the what you desire. ;-)