# How to remove Create and Import here in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo

I have following module in this module I wanted it to display in Form view .I dont have any records fields too just some single line diagram we have added at .xml file and that is static

[image]

Comment: you can do it by adding security right for that User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add security file in your custom module.

For example: *security/ir.model.access.csv*

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
unique_id, test.name, model_test_name, group_name_test_user, 1,1,0,0
```

For import link you may follow [openerp-import-and-export-menu-not-shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21727723/in-openerp-import-and-export-menu-not-shown/21727766#21727766)

You need to make it **False**

NOTE:

Don't forget to add file in openerp.py file

Answer (score 0):

Un update for this Question as the Current Odoo's version is 14.0.0

Another way to just remove (or add) Create & Import is to act directly on the
XML view of the Tree.

### To toggle Create & Import, on the tree view use these attributes

```
<record id="model_name_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">model.name.view.tree</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>    
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <tree string="My Tree View" create="false" import="false">
            <!--   Data....      -->
        </tree>

    </field>
</record>
```

***However, if you disable create (`create="false"`) it will disable import as well as you can't create new records (importing you will create new record right?)  so you could just put `create=false'***

---

### Toggle Create & Import from an existing View (inheriting)

```
<record id="model_name_view_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">model.name.view.tree</field>
    <field name="model">model.name</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.model_name_inherited"/>
    <field name="priority">50</field> <!-- Higher priority means lower hierarchy, adviced to add it | Default 16 -->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <tree string="My Tree View" create="false" import="false">
            <!--   Data....      -->
        </tree>

    </field>
</record>
```

---

### Odoo Documentation

- Advised to read --> [Views | List](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/views.html#list)